# hash containing an array to array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I've read through quite a few of posts, but none seem to do just this, which is a bit tricky.

Say I have a hash that contains an array as one of its values.

```
hash = {
  :a => 'one', 
  :arr => [
    {:id => 'ten',    :amount => 10, :b => 'two'}, 
    {:id => 'twenty', :amount => 20, :b => 'two'},
    {:id => 'apple',  :amount => 7,  :b => 'applesauce'}
  ], 
  :c => 3
}
```

I want to convert this to an array of hashes (which would be of the size of the contained array), as follows:

```
# => [
  {:a => 'one', :id => 'ten',    :amount => 10, :b => 'two',        :c => 3},
  {:a => 'one', :id => 'twenty', :amount => 20, :b => 'two',        :c => 3},
  {:a => 'one', :id => 'apple',  :amount => 7,  :b => 'applesauce', :c => 3}
]
```

The conversion should maintain whatever key/value pairs are inside and outside the array, and ideally I could pass in the key of the array to ask it perform the action:

```
flatten_hash_array(hash, :arr)
```

I realize that the Ruby `flatten` in the Array class is not what we need. Grasping for a verb! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the job, barring validity checks.

```
def flatten_hash_array(hash, key)
  hash[key].map {|entry| entry.merge(hash.reject {|k| k == key})}
end
```

Comment: Awesome! the hash.reject block just needs to be passed k,v and it works like a charm. Thanks!

    def flatten_hash_array(hash, key)
      hash[key].map {|entry| entry.merge(hash.reject {|k,v| k == key})}
    end

Comment: Hmm, must be a 1.8 / 1.9 difference - my Ruby accepts `hash.reject {|k|}`, even though there are two params available. But hey - glad it works for you.